# What motivated hyperbolic functions?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

In college, the hyperbolic functions as were just presented with no real motivation. I've been wondering where they came from historically, and in particular how they came to be used to parameterize hyperbolas. Wolfram hasn't really helped. Anyone know where to look?

I've made some guesses.

If we have $x^2-y^2=1$, then $(x+y)(x-y)=1$. If we have $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, then we have $uv=1$.

If we want another pair $u'v'=1$, then we can let $u'=ku$ and $v'=v/k$ for some real k. This selection of $u'$ and $v'$ implies new values for $x$ and $y$, call them $x'$ and $y'$. Further since $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$ and $y$, $x'$ and $y'$ are ultimately themselves functions of x and y.

To wit:

$$x'= (\frac{k+1/k}{2})x+(\frac{k-1/k}{2})y$$
$$y' = (\frac{k-1/k}{2})x+(\frac{k+1/k}{2})y$$

Now, $(0,1)$ is a point on the hyperbola in question and simplifies arbitrary points on the hyperbola to functions of $k$.

$$x'=\frac{k+1/k}{2}$$
$$y'=\frac{k-1/k}{2}$$

If we assume $k$ is an arbitrary differential function of parameter $t$ we have with some rearranging:

$$\frac{dx'}{dt}=\frac{y'}{k}\frac{dk}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dy'}{dt}=\frac{x'}{k}\frac{dk}{dt}$$

From here I don't see a straight forward motivation for the next step. The usual parameterization follows if we take $\frac{1}{k}\frac{dk}{dt}$ to be identically 1. That seems a fairly arbitrary if convenient choice. Apparently the parameter that was chosen has something to do with a related area, but I'm not sure what that is either.

Is any of this related to that?

Comment: If you're looking for the actual history, then the [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask.

Comment: off the top of my head, I believe one application can be found in using Newton's second law to predict the trajectory of a particle while accounting for air resistance

Comment: I second @Blue suggestion.  In this group, you are likely to get "I think" answers with no references.  In hsm you may actually get some information.

Comment: For the circular functions, $\begin{cases}x=\cos t,\\y=\sin t\end{cases}\iff x^2+y^2=1$ (circle), and for the hyperbolic counterparts, $\begin{cases}x=\cosh t,\\y=\sinh t\end{cases}\iff x^2-y^2=1$ (hyperbola).

Comment: Hyperbolic functions are just certain combinations of the exponential function, which we have given certain names as an abbreviation. They are called $\sinh$, etc. because they have analogues to many of the well known trig formulas, e.g $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$, among others.

Answer (score 3):

Useful references, arranged chronologically. Barnett's 2004 paper is probably the most relevant to your question.

John Casey, [**A Treatise on Plane Trigonometry, containing an Account of Hyperbolic Functions**](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00caseuoft) (1888)

James McMahon, [**Hyperbolic Functions**](https://archive.org/details/hyperbolicfuncti031883mbp) (1906, 4th edition)

V. G. Shervatov, [**Hyperbolic Functions**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0006AXDJE) (1963; [2007 Dover reprint](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486458865))

Janet Heine Barnett, [*Enter, stage center: the early drama of the hyperbolic functions*](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/321922717729.pdf.bannered.pdf) (2004)